# Zeros of a finite sum

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to answer the question that, suppose $$g_{n}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!z^{k}}$$ and let $\epsilon>0$,  for large enough $n$, are all the zeros of $g_{n}$ in the disk $D(0;\epsilon)$? I try to apply the Rouche's theorem but I couldn't so any help will be great.

Comment: Do we still have uniformly convergence? Doesn't  $\frac{1}{z}$ make any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Study $h_n(z) = g_n(1/z)$ instead. On any bounded set, $h_n(z)$ converges uniformly to a well-known function.

Comment: In fact I used that relation before I posted the question to apply Hurwitz's theorem so I showed the statement for $h_{n}$ but how can I pass to the $g_{n}$? Thanks.